# Delete a specific element in array using recursion C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I've implemented a iterative cancellation of a given element in a array structure, but I'm not able to create a recursive version, any help?

```
struct array *delete_elem (struct array *q, int val){

    for (int i = 0; i < q->size + 1; i++) {
        if (val == q->A[i].integer) {
            q->size--;
            for (int j = i; j < q->size + 1; j++)
                q->A[j] = q->A[j+1];
        }
    }
    return q;

}
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion here. I recommend making a stab at it and then sharing code as a [mcve] if you get stuck, but keep in mind this is a pretty bad use case for recursion: more overhead and your stack might blow for no reason if you array is big enough. Iterative is definitely the way to go, absent an instructor forcing you to recurse. Also, the specification isn't quite clear when there are multiple elements that match `val`, so you may wish to clarify the spec a bit on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion can be pretty tough to understand sometimes. I don't commonly find myself having a need for it, and I usually prefer an iterative approach. That being said, you need to break down your problem into what you want to do, which is:

- Scan through the array searching for the value.
- Once it finds it, "delete it", by
- moving all of the remaining values over by one space.

Here's an example:

```
struct array {
   int *values;
   int size;
   int maxSize;
};

void shift( struct array *arr, int to, int from ) {
   if( from >= arr->size ) return; // Done.

   arr->values[to] = arr->values[from];
   return shift( arr, to + 1, from + 1);
}

void recursiveSearchAndDelete( struct array *arr, int value, int index ) {
   if( index >= arr->size ) return; // Didn't find it.

   if( arr->values[index] == value ) {
      // Found it, delete it.
      shift( arr, index, index + 1 );
      arr->size--;
      return;
   }
   return recursiveSearchAndDelete( arr, value, index + 1 );
}

int main() {
   struct array myArray;
   myArray.size = myArray.maxSize = 10;
   myArray.values = (int*)malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
   for( int i = 0; i < myArray.size; i++ ) myArray.values[i] = i * 10;

   printf( "Original size: %d\n", myArray.size );
   recursiveSearchAndDelete( &myArray, 50, 0 );
   printf( "New size: %d\n", myArray.size );
   for( int i = 0; i < myArray.size; i++ ) 
      printf( "%d\n", myArray.values[i] );

   return 0;
}
```

I always try to write `return` wherever possible when calling functions recursively. We don't really care about any return value, and C compilers do this optimization for you already, but some other languages require `return` to do a *tail call*, meaning, an extra stack entry isn't created for each step of the recursion. That means that you can iterate through a billion entries without going a billion stack entries deep.

It's also obvious that recursion can convolute your functions a lot of the time. I especially hate passing around arguments everywhere to keep a state during recursion. Recursion makes certain algorithms easier to understand, and other ones harder. Look at the Fibonacci sequence for an example of an easy function to implement with recursion.

Comment: Tanks a lot! You literally helped me out, I really got it now, thank you!